# Error while Upgrading OSX El Capitan GM Beta "This core operation is not allowed on a sparse logical volume group"

Tags: macos, operating-systems, macbook, osx-yosemite, osx-el-capitan

I'm trying to upgrade my Mid 2014 Macbook pro from OSX Yosemite to El Capitan GM Beta. I have downloaded update today but while upgrading, installation stops and throws the following error.

> **OS X could not be installed on your computer**
>
> This core storage operation is not allowed on a sparse logical volume group. Quit the installer to restart your computer and try again.

Anybody know how to fix this error?

Your help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many researches on Apple technical forum, I found that one of the possible cause for the error

> This core storage operation is not allowed on a sparse logical volume group. Quit the installer to restart your computer and try again

is **FileVault encryption incompatibilities**. I looked up in my Macbook for FileVault settings, the FileValt was turned off in my machine. I Enabled FileVault encryption and tried OSX El Capitan upgrade again. This time installation completed without any error.

This solution worked fine for me.